# Equivalance of Vector Bundle Definitions

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I try to learn about manifolds and I am working with the two textbooks "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Tu and Lee's book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". After comparing the two definitions of Vector Bundles in the books I got a question.

Lee defines on pp.249/250: Let $M$ be a topological space. A real vector bundle of rank $k$ over $M$ is a topological space $E$ with a surjective continuous map $\pi\colon E\to M$ satisfying the conditions:

(i) For each $p∈ M$ the fibre $E_p=\pi^{-1}(p)$ over $P$ is endowed with the structure of a $k$-dimensional real vector space.

(ii) For each $p∈ M$ there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ and a homeomorphism $\phi\colon \pi^{-1}(U) \to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfying the conditions:

1. $\pi_U \circ \phi = \pi$ where $\pi_U\colon U\times \mathbb{R}^k\to U$ is the projection)
2. for each $q∈U$ the restriction of $\phi$ to $E_q$ is a vectorspace isomorphism from $E_q$ to $\{q\}\times \mathbb{R}^k$.

The definition by Tu looks almost the same (changing "topological spaces" to "manifolds" for $E$ and $M$, "continuous" to "smooth" for $\pi$ and "homeomorphism" to "diffeomorphism" for $\phi$). But Tu omits the condition (ii)(1) -- instead he insists that $\phi$ has to be fibre-preserving. So my question is if these definitions are equivalent. I think it has something to do with the Exercise 12.5 in Tu's book where he asks the reader to prove an equivalent statement for a map to be fibre-preserving. Having this in mind I still don't see why Lee is insisting that $\pi_U$ has to be the projection-map. Do you have an idea? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want to add something: Does the fact that Tu says $\phi$ has to be fiber-preserving need a reference to concrete maps (say $\pi$ and $\pi_U$ for example) because the fibers depend on these maps?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent. I'm not sure I understand your questions?
Were you able to do exercise 12.5? It seems like an unpacking of Tu's definition of fiber-preserving, which is right above that exercise. The statement that the diagram in exercise 12.5 commutes is your condition (ii)(1).
Not sure what you mean by needing "a reference to concrete maps", or "insisting that $\pi_U$ has to be the projection map". Maybe you can elaborate your question a little more?

Comment: Dear Keshav, thank you for your answer. I was misthinking about the notion of a map being fibre-preserving. A map $\phi$ is called fibre-preserving, if I can take any two maps $\pi$ and $\pi'$, look at their fibers $E_p$ and $E_p'$ at any point $p$ and the statement $\phi(E_p)⊂E_p'$ is true.

Yes, I tried to prove the statement.

My problem is the following: Let's take a vector bundle defined in way Tu describes it. Then the map $\phi$ is fiber-preserving and I know with the help of the exercise, that $\pi=\pi'\circ \phi$. So it is a vector bundle in the sense of Lee.
But now I take a ...

Comment: ... a vector bundle in the sense of Lee. Then I know that the maps $\phi$, $\pi$ and $\pi_U$ as the projection fulfill the equation $\pi_U\circ \phi = \pi$ as it is one of the conditions. But how do I know now, that $\phi$ is a fibre-preserving map? My problem is that I have to check $\pi'\circ \phi = \pi$ is true for any $\pi'$ and $\pi$ and not only the special $\pi'=\pi_U$ and the given $\pi$ for $\phi$ to be fibre-preserving.

Comment: (I cannot edit my first comment, but the $\pi'$ in the last line should be the special §\pi'=\pi_U$)

Comment: Oh, I see. You are still thinking of fiber preserving incorrectly (unless this is what you meant by misthinking about it). The projections $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are given in the definition of fiber preserving. "**Given two maps $\pi:E\to M$ and $\pi':E'\to M$**, a map $\phi$ is called fiber preserving if ..." So the maps $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are fixed. In the above case, they are $\pi$ and $\pi_U$ only. I think if it were true for any such projection maps you could probably make an argument that $\phi$ must be the identity or something.

Comment: Dear Keshav, you're absolutly right, thank you very much for your help. My understanding of fiber-preserving above would not make a lot of sense. With the correct interpretation of fiber-preserving my initial question remains: When Tu insists that the map $\phi$ has to be fiber-preserving doesn't he have to say "a fibre-preserving map $\phi$ with respect to the fibers produced by the maps $\phi$ and the projection map $\phi_U$?

Comment: corrected: "... produced by the maps$\pi$ and the projection map $\pi_U$" should be in the last line, sorry